# ui:include includes wrong file in JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Accorrding to the [documentation of ui:include tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/include.html)

> Use this tag—which is very similar to JSP's jsp:include—to encapsulate
>   and reuse content among multiple XHTML pages. There are three things
>   this tag can include: plain XHTML, and XHTML pages that have either a
>   composition tag or a component tag.
>
> You supply a filename, through ui:include's src attribute for JSF to
>   include. That filename is relative to the XHTML file that was rendered
>   as a result of the last request. So, for example, if JSF loaded the
>   view login.xhtml, and that file included pageDecorations/header.xhtml,
>   and pageDecorations/header.xhtml included companyLogo.xhtml, **then
>   companyLogo.xhtml will not be found if it's in the pageDecorations
>   directory, because companyLogo.xhtml has to be in the same directory
>   as login.xhtml.**

---

I created a simple test:
**webapp/login.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:body>

    <ui:include src="pageDecorations/header.xhtml" />

</h:body>
</html>
```

---

**webapp/pageDecorations/header.xhtml**

```
<ui:include 
        src="logo.xhtml"

        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
/>
```

---

**webapp/pageDecorations/logo.xhtml**

```
<h:outputText 
      value="Logo in /pageDecorations" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
/>
```

---

**webapp/logo.xhtml**

```
<h:outputText value="Logo in /" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

/>
```

---

When I ran this test (loaded login.xhtml page) using JSF 2.2 on WildFly 10.1 , I got `Logo in /pageDecorations`, while according to the documentation it should be: `Logo in /`
What is wrong ? Is there a bug in the documentation or Mojarra implementation ? 
Or my understanding is wrong ?

Comment: Yes webapp/pageDecorations/logo.xhtml should be call, because you are currently inside webapp/pageDecorations/ and it will find webapp/pageDecorations/logo.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are inside **webapp/** and executing `webapp/login.xhtml` 
inside that you get `src="pageDecorations/header.xhtml"` and for exectuing that you are in **pageDecorations** and from header.xhtml you are tring to find src="logo.xhtml" which will you get in the same directory (**pageDecorations**) so it will print 
**"Logo in /pageDecorations"** .
Document looks wrong in this case.